# is that possible to trigger another gestureRecognizer in one gestureRecognizer (in swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, gesture

if i click image long then func actionLongPress get started and as you can see, if i click image long then i want to move that image along my touch... but this code doesn't work...
there is no error. even though i click image long, image doesn't follow my touch..
do you fix this trouble???

```
@objc func actionLongPress(Recog : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if Recog.state == .began{
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) 
            addPanGesture(view: addedImage)
            origin = addedImage.frame.origin
            
        } else if Recog.state == .ended{
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) 
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one state that you need to implement ... which is state change

```
@objc func actionLongPress(Recog : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if Recog.state == .began{
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) 
            addPanGesture(view: addedImage)
            origin = addedImage.frame.origin
            
        } else if Recog.state == .changed {

            // assign view frame here

           let location = Recog.location(in: self)
             your_view?.center = targetPosition

         } else if Recog.state == .ended{
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) 
            
        }
    }
```